# How to hold the specific int values in my database column

Tags: java, database

How can i assign my variables to hold the specific values in my database? so that i can easily calculate the value. EXAMPLE : int price = databasespecificvalue;
int totalprice = price * quantity;

Comment: Just Google how to use your specific database application with Java. This is very broad.

Comment: Are familiar with [`JDBC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)?

Comment: Can't find any answer